# Can normal titans dig the ground?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I know normal titans are not intelligent but in one of the episodes of season 1 we see that they can learn to climb the trees in order to reach the scouts. 
So why none of them tried digging a tunnel in the ground to pass the walls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Can normal titans dig the ground?**

Yes, they can. In **Season 2 Episode 10** we see

> Ymir digging herself out of the ground as a pure titan.

**2. So why none of them tried digging a tunnel in the ground to pass the walls?**

In **Season 1 Episode 25** at around 15 minutes the intermission cards state the following (synopsis):

> Once a miner tried to dig under wall Sheena. At some point, however,
>  the ground was so hard that his shovel broke. He wondered if the
>  people were surrounded by walls not only above the ground, but below
>  the ground, too.
>  
>  The next day the miner disappeared and was no longer findable. Unsure
>  what to do, his friend eventually went to the Garrison, and told them
>  the whole Story. The Military Police and the Garrison
>  organized a large-scale search party. But they never found a trace of
>  the miner, nor even the pit he'd dug. And one day, his friend also
>  vanished, never to be seen again.

From this we can conclude that titans cannot get past the walls through digging.